# implement PlayFair encryption on string entered by user in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, encryption

Am working on a project that should ask user for string `input` and then ask user to choose `encryption` algorithm which may include `substitution cipher,play fair cipher, transposition cipher, Product cipher and RSA cipher`. I have managed to implement `substitution` cypher with success. It takes user input, encrypts it and prints out the `original message`, the `cipher` and the `deciphered` message...
I need help implementing the rest of the algorithms taking `message` as a parameter in each of the functions while printing out the `orighanl message, cipher and deciphered cipher`, Thank You.
Here is the code am using so far...

```
import random
##function to make encryption decryption key for substitution encryption
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.,! '
key = 'nu.t!iyvxqfl,bcjrodhkaew spzgm'
plaintext = "Hey, this is really fun!"

##All these functions are substituion based

def makeKey(alphabet):
   alphabet = list(alphabet)
   random.shuffle(alphabet)
   return ''.join(alphabet)

def encrypt(plaintext, key, alphabet):
    keyMap = dict(zip(alphabet, key))
    return ''.join(keyMap.get(c.lower(), c) for c in plaintext)

def decrypt(cipher, key, alphabet):
    keyMap = dict(zip(key, alphabet))
    return ''.join(keyMap.get(c.lower(), c) for c in cipher)



message=input("Enter the message you want encrypted")
if(message.isalpha() and message.__len__()!=0):
    options=("1. Substitution Cypher","2.Playfair Cypher","3. Transposition Cypher", "4. Product Cypher","RSA Cypher")
    print("Choose an encryption Cypher you would like to use?")
    print(options[0])
    print(options[1])
    print(options[2])
    print(options[3])


    choice=int(input("Please reply with a number for choice of Cypher"))

    if((choice>=1)&(choice<=4)):
        if(choice==1):
            ##print("You chose 1")
            print(message)
            cipher=encrypt(message,key,alphabet)
            print (encrypt(message,key,alphabet))
            print(decrypt(cipher,key,alphabet))
        elif(choice==2):
            print("You chose 2")
        elif(choice==3):
          print("You chose 3")
        else:
         print("You chose 4")
    else:
        print("nThe input choice you entered is out of rage")
else:
    print("User input is required in form of alphabet format")
```

Comment: Don't try to code all the options at once.  Code each option separately and test it thoroughly as a stand-alone program.  Only add that module into the main program when it is working correctly.  And Playfair is a single word.

Comment: Thanks man, you really helped